# Generate link with array

Tags: php, arrays

I want generate a link using two array: the first one contains addresses; the second one contains text.
I want have:

```
 - <a href="address1">text3</a>
 - <a href="address2">text3</a>
 - <a href="address3">text3</a>
```

to do so I tried like this but I can't generate texts.

```
<ul>
            <?php
isset($_GET["page"]) ? $page=$_GET["page"] : $page="home";
$vocimenu=array("address1","address2","address3");
$nomimenu=array("text1","text2","text3");
$nome=array_values($nomimenu);
foreach($vocimenu as $voce) {
  echo "<li>";
  if($page!=$voce) echo '<a href="?page='.$voce.'">';
  echo $nome;
  if($page!=$voce) echo "</a>";
  echo "</li>";
}
?>
        </ul>
```

Comment: use for() instead of foreach()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use one array

```
isset($_GET["page"]) ? $page=$_GET["page"] : $page="home";
$links=array("address1"=>"text1","address2"=>"text2","address3"=>"text3");

foreach($links as $href=>$text){
   if($page!=$voce){
      echo '<a href="?page='.$href.'">'.$text.'</a>';
   }else{
      echo $text;
   }

}
```

Comment: This one is even better! Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
isset($_GET["page"]) ? $page=$_GET["page"] : $page="home";
$vocimenu=array("address1","address2","address3");
$nomimenu=array("text1","text2","text3");

//since you're using two arrays, foreach is not the way to go
//you need a counter so you can get elements from each array
for ($i=0;$i<count($vocimenu);$i++) { 
  echo "<li>";
  if($page!=$voce) echo '<a href="?page='.$vocimenu[$i].'">';
  echo $nomimenu[$i];
  if($page!=$voce) echo "</a>";
  echo "</li>";
}
```

An alternate option is to do it like this, but that could make some of your other code less flexible:

```
$array = array("address1"=>"value1","address2"=>"value2",...);
foreach($array as $address=>$value){
    echo "<li>";
    if($page!=$voce) echo '<a href="?page='.$address.'">';
    echo $value;
    if($page!=$voce) echo "</a>";
    echo "</li>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks both of you! I knew I needed a counter but I wasn't able to do it.

Answer (score 0):

It would be much easier if you create an associative array:

```
$menu = array(
    "fmp_trama" => "Full Metal Panic!",
    "fumoffu_trama" => "Full Metal Panic? Fumoffu",
    "fmp_tsr" => "Full Metal Panic! TSR"
);

echo '<ul>';
foreach ($menu as $key => $value) {
    echo "<li>";
    if($page != $key) {
        echo sprintf('<a href="?page=%s">%s</a>', $key, $value);
    }
    else {
        echo sprintf('<span>%s</span>', $value);
    }
    echo "</li>";
}
echo '</ul>';
```

You can build the array like this: (if you are bound to the 2 array structure)

```
$menu = array_combine($vocimenu, $nomimenu);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Yes is much easier like this. Much readable.